# Why does a database query in python not return an integer value?

Tags: python, sql, web

Why does this work:

```
cash = db.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = :user_id", user_id = session["user_id"])

# Ensure user can afford the stock
if cash[0]["cash"] < share * quote["price"]:
    return apology("Not enough money")
```

and this doesn't:

```
cash = db.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = :user_id", user_id = session["user_id"])

# Ensure user can afford the stock
if cash < share * quote["price"]:
    return apology("Not enough money")
```

I would like to understand how DB queries work in python. What is that "cash" variable stores? Isn't it the cash value for a user? (int)

Comment: Which python module are you using for the `db` object?

Comment: It returns some number of results (a sequence) of some number of columns (a dictionary) of some values (in this case, a number).  An int isn't enough to handle all possible results from a call to `execute`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `db.execute` returns a matrix/table structure. In this particular example, that matrix is called cash, which has only one column again named cash, and has only one value in it.

So let's modify your query slightly to understand it better. If your query was:

```
result = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :user_id", user_id = session["user_id"])
```

That result would hypothetically look like:

[all columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tgBR.png)

And when you query this:

```
result[0]["cash"]
```

It would return 100.

If you select only `cash` instead of `*`, you'll get only one column of this table (which is what you are doing):

[cash column only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGPHp.png)

And again, `result[0]["cash"]` will give you 100.

If I were you I wouldn't `select *`. `select cash` is good because it fetches only what it needs. If you want to store that cash value to use it later, call the database the same way you do now, and just create a variable `cashValue = result[0]["cash"]` and use that. Also, don't name different objects the same name, it will confuse you. If there is a column in the database table named `cash`, call your output something else, like `result`. And then if you want to get the value in it, call it again something else, like `cashValue`.

Hope this clarifies things.

Comment: Thanks a lot, really appreciate your help

Comment: You are very welcome, @Quarkendon. I appreciate it if you can click the "checkmark" next to the most helpful answer to mark it as accepted. Thanks and good luck!

Answer (score 1):

What you receive in `cash` is a result set. You can think of it as a table like structure.

So `cash[0]` means the "row" on index 0 and `cash[0][cash]` means "field" cash in "row" on index 0

Comment: Thanks Sir,  Does that mean that i could have used:
   'code'  cash = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :user_id", user_id = session["user_id"])

    # Ensure user can afford the stock
    if cash[0]["cash"] < share * quote["price"]:
        return apology("Not enough money")

Does it make sense to SELECT cash instead of SELECT *?

Comment: @Quarkendon I think this could work too, depending on your DB driver (the [Python DB API](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) doesnt specify this explicitly). You could just try it out. -Edit-: But be aware, that `SELECT * ...` is not good practice. Better to select explicit than implicit.